# Set multiple sliders value and linked text fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I got three buttons which should set the value for a group of sliders and the textfields for the slider value output. The function does however only change one of the sliders.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/josepha/anb9G/

```
//slider
$("#slider-design").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 2,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount-design").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$("#amount-design").val($("#slider-design").slider("value"));

$("#slider-pages").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 5,
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount-pages").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$("#amount-pages").val($("#slider-pages").slider("value"));

$("#slider-hours").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 5,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount-hours").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$("#amount-hours").val($("#slider-hours").slider("value"));

$("#preset-small").click(function () {
    $("#slider-pages").slider("value", 5);
    $("#slider-design").slider("value", 1);
    $("#slider-hours").slider("value", 5);
});
```

Comment: I don't see any issue. All 3 sliders work fine

Comment: To echo DKM, the sliders work fine. What could be throwing you off is the fact the first/last one is set to 5 which is the same as the starting values for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the `slide` event is not triggered by value/option method, but only when you interact with the slider itself.

Doc: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138059/Slider#specs

You can change it using the [`change`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) event, that is triggered in value/option set too.

Code:

```
//slider
$("#slider-design").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 2,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount-design").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$("#amount-design").val($("#slider-design").slider("value"));

$("#slider-pages").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 5,
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount-pages").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$("#amount-pages").val($("#slider-pages").slider("value"));

$("#slider-hours").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 5,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount-hours").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$("#amount-hours").val($("#slider-hours").slider("value"));
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anb9G/1/